# Editing a program in vim while it's running

Tags: shell, vim, command-line

Hi I would like to know if I am running a code on command line in the background, and then while it is still running, I edit that code with vim, would it affect the currently running code?

Comment: Probably not. How do you run the code?

Comment: Just like `./program.sh &`

Comment: IIRC it crashes if you do that on Solaris.

Comment: Only when you save. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51420587/opening-a-config-file-in-a-vim-editor-while-being-used-by-a-script/51439646#51439646

Answer (score 3):

No, the changes won't come into play until you save the file and run the program again.

Answer (score 1):

No, this would not be possible, since the code you edit in vim is just in a vim internal buffer. Vim therefore always needs the user to enter `:w` to write the buffers contents out to a file (save it to the disk). Then you could run it again `./script`.